# OCaml compiler error "variant type list has no constructor true"

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I have been learning OCaml and have been trying to write a function that takes in a list of lists of type int, which are representing a matrix. For example: `[[1;2;3]; [4;5;6]; [7;8;9]]` and in return I want to return a bool value indicating if it is a proper matrix, or not. The way this is decided is if all rows in the matrix have the same amount of elements (like the example shown above)

Thus, I have created the following function:

```
let rec matrix lst =
  match lst with
  | h::t -> 
    (match h with
    | a ->
      if (List.length a = List.length (matrix t)) then true else false)
```

My function type is not what I'm expecting. It should just be

```
is_matrix : (int list) list -> bool
```

or the general equivalent with a'

I'm getting a compile error saying: the variant type list has no constructor true Any idea what's that about?

```
let rec getlength x =
  match x with
  | [] -> 0
  | a::b -> List.length a + getlength b


let matrix lst =
  match lst with 
  | [] -> true
  | h::t -> if (getlength h = getlength t) then true else false
```

Comment: the code you provided does not compile (around the 2nd List.length).

Comment: @PierreG. Hello Pierre. Yes, I am aware of that, that is the current code I have written, which is not compiling (type error) thus what i'm asking help with

Comment: Ok - I understood that you managed to get your function compiled but that it signature was not the expected one.

Comment: No! Sorry for the mixup, my mistake actually

Comment: Please see my update! :)

Comment: as already mentionned below : since (matrix t) is supposed to be a boolean and not a list, List.length (matrix t) has no meaning... Other point : the second match instruction is useless : when there is a match, then a=h; so keep only the following -> and replace a by h.

Comment: Pierre, I think I understood your point, I will try fixing this now.

Comment: I am confused, are is_matrix and matrix the same ? If yes, then (matrix t) is a bool - and is therefore not compatible with List.length.  There is 2 match statement in your code, the second one is useless for the reason I quote.

Comment: yes is_matrix and matrix is the same!

Comment: @PierreG. please see new updated code at the bottom of the post. I am not getting the correct type I want when it compiles

Comment: this is because getlength signature is : `a list list -> int` - where `\`a` can be anything including a list type. Then matrix matches lst to h::t where h is the head of lst. Since you apply getlength to h; the type of h is `\`a list list`. h being the head of lst (which is a list), it implies that the type of lst is a list of `\`a list list\ i.e. `\`a list list list`  which is not what you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is wrong because of `List.length a = List.length (matrix t)` normally `matrix t` is a boolean, so it's not really clear what does `List.length true` means.

In your second solution the problem is in `h::t -> if (getlength h = getlength t)`. `getlength` is of type `'a list list -> int`, so you can't call it with type, let say, `'b` (type of `h`) and then with type `'b list` (type of `t`).

But in general I think you are moving in right direction. Simple algorithm may looking like this:

1. Calculate length of the first element of list,
2. For each remaining element calculate its length and compare it with result of (1), if they are equal continue, else return `false`.
3. Return `true` if there is no more elements.

This algorithm can be implemented in many different way. I strongly recommend you to do it yourself, but I can't resist to post this simple and elegant solution:

```
let matrix (h::t) =
    let l = List.length h in
    let rec f = function
        | [] -> true
        | h::t -> if List.length h = l then f t
                  else false in
    f t
```

Once again, be sure that you fully understand this code before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following expression:

```
List.length matrix t
```

This tries to apply `List.length` to two arguments: `matrix` and `t`. This function only takes one argument (a list), so this reports a type error.

Comment: That makes sense! Now however, I'm getting a compile error saying: the variant type list has no constructor true Any idea what's that about?

Comment: matrix is expected to return a boolean I guess... So what is the meaning of List.length matrix t or List.length (matrix t)  ; that is List.length boolean

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the case for `[[]]` if you want the type system to understand that you're working with lists of lists.

```
| [[]] -> true
```

This would then mean you can use `List.length` on the lists like your originaly wanted.